# Qual é a finalidade do diretório Assets?

Tags: unity3d, diretório

Estou começando aprender a respeito da Unity, e no meu primeiro projeto me surgiu uma dúvida em relação ao diretório **Assets**. Nele contem alguns arquivos que são scripts em C# do jogo, e outros arquivos de extensão `*.asset` e `*.meta`, há outros diretórios e outros tipos de arquivos também.

Assim sendo, eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade do diretório *Assets* em projetos feitos com a Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Ele armazena tudo que você quer colocar dentro do jogo, tipo: baixei uma casa em 3D para o meu jogo, então para fazer o unity reconhecer esse objeto, tem que botar ele dentro dessa pasta e tudo que você cria dentro do unity, assim como os scripts e outros, fica tudo dentro dessa pasta.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do Bits of Bytes está correta. Só algumas informações complementares para ficar mais claro ainda:

Você pode imaginar a pasta Assets como o conteúdo do seu jogo que ficará no HD, disponível para ser acessada durante o jogo, enquanto o que está em sua cena atual é o que está na memória RAM. Assim sendo, o seu jogo pode ter alguns gigas no seu tamanho final mas suas cenas só vão levar para memória RAM os objetos que estão presentes nela.

A pasta Assets que você vê com a Unity aberto é a mesma que está no projeto, vista no explorer. Porém, dentro da Unity, arquivos como os .meta são ocultados. Esses arquivos servem para o controle interno de determinado asset, como por exemplo onde ele esta sendo usado, suas propriedades etc.